# How to combine 'if' and 'else' code using cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted to create an `if` and `else` statement for the code provided below. The code should work as follow:
When running the batch code, it will find out whether the path has been written on the `addon.cfg` file or not. If it has not been written yet, then the batch file will write the path. If the path is present, then it will delete the path completely.

The batch code is a as below:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4"
Set "Val=SetupPath"

For %%A In (Cmd Reg)Do Set "%%A=%SystemRoot%\System32\%%A.exe"
If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 Set "Cmd=%SystemRoot%\SysNative\cmd.exe"
Set "Dir="
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('
    ""%Cmd%" /D /C ""%Reg%" Query "%Key%" /V "%Val%" 2^>Nul""')Do Set "Dir=%%~B"
If Not Defined Dir GoTo :EOF
If "%Dir:~-1%"=="\" Set "Dir=%Dir:~,-1%"
REM VARMA Scenery Designs Batch Script for Prepar3D V4
REM Add the current Folder to the Addon Library (add-on.cfg)
set args=-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Add, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%cd%
start "" "%Dir%\Prepar3D.exe" "%args%"
```

The `if` and `else` code should be something like this:

```
if  addon == ""
   set args=-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Add, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%cd%
else
   set args=-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Remove, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%cd%
```

But, I am not sure what values/codes should be inside the **`""`** on `if addon == ""`

**[Edit/]**

The `addon.cfg` file is located on `C:\ProgramData\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4`.
The batch file will look for `addon.xml` file (this file will have some details where Prepar3D should look for the scenery files from) in the same location where the batch file is placed. That is why the the path is written as `Path=%cd%` in the above code.

Sample code in `addon.cfg` file:

```
[Package.0]
PATH=F:\Flight Simulators\Addon\Scenery Making Tools\WMKM Model\WMKM Airport Design\Melaka International Airport (WMKM)\P3D V4\Melaka International Airport (WMKM)
ACTIVE=true
REQUIRED=false
```

Sample code in `addon.xml` file:

```
<SimBase.Document Type="AddOnXml" version="4,0" id="add-on">
  <AddOn.Name>VARMA Scenery Designs-(WMKM) Melaka International Airport</AddOn.Name>
  <AddOn.Description>Scenery for (WMKM) Melaka International Airport by VARMA Scenery Designs</AddOn.Description>

  <!--
  add-on.xml will work "first read first in" such that the last component read will be on top.
  -->  

  <AddOn.Component>
    <Category>Scenery</Category>
    <Path>scenery</Path>
    <Name>VARMA Scenery Designs-WMKM scenery</Name>
  </AddOn.Component>

</SimBase.Document>
```

You may refer [here](http://www.prepar3d.com/SDKv4/sdk/add-ons/add-on_configuration_files.html#Options) for the `add-on configuration file` details with some examples.

Comment: Your question does not make sense to anyone but yourself, _and possibly those who are familiar with adding and removing addons in Prepar3D v4_. In order to get help specific to the program, you need to fully explain the process, what is required, and what defines both the `If` and `Else`. *Please don't just link to a website and expect us to learn the configuration of the program ourselves*.

Comment: Based on your previous question, my understanding is that `Add` will add the script directory path, (not `%cd%`, _see my answer_), to the add-on library, `add-on.cfg`. I'm assuming therefore that you may need to read and parse the `add-on.cfg` file for the script directory path, `if` it isn't found, `set` the value as `Add`, `else` `set` the value as `Remove`. Can you please expand on that, or offer an alternative scenario; thank you.

Comment: The syntax for `IF ELSE` is clearly defined in the help file for the `IF` command.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code example for you:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
    Start "" /D "%__CD__%" "%SystemRoot%\SysNative\cmd.exe" /C "%~f0"&Exit /B)
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4"
Set "Val=SetupPath"
Set "Dir="
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%Key%" /V "%Val%" 2^>Nul'
)Do Set "Dir=%%~B"
If Not Defined Dir GoTo :EOF
If "%Dir:~-1%"=="\" Set "Dir=%Dir:~,-1%"
Set "Cfg=Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4\add-ons.cfg"
Set "Pad=%~dp0"
Set "Pth=%Pad:~,-1%"
Set "Arg=-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Path=%Pth:,=&comma;%"
Set "Act=Add"
Rem Enter your FileLocation below. [ProgramData|Local|Roaming]
Set "Lcn=ProgramData"
If /I "%Lcn%"=="ProgramData" Set "Cfg=%ProgramData%\%Cfg%"
If /I "%Lcn%"=="Local" Set "Cfg=%LocalAppData%\%Cfg%"
If /I "%Lcn%"=="Roaming" Set "Cfg=%AppData%\%Cfg%"
If Exist "%Cfg%" Find /I "PATH=%Pth%"<"%Cfg%">Nul&&Set "Act=Remove"
Set "Arg=%Arg%, FileLocation=%Lcn%, Operation=%Act%"
Start "" "%Dir%\Prepar3D.exe" "%Arg%"
```

*Please note that I have added a `Rem`arked line with an instruction, whilst not necessary for the purposes of this specific task, it affords you the opportunity to adjust the location for the other two possible options.*

Comment: Please refer the [Edit/] section on the question where i have added few details about the location of the files with some sample codes of the files.

Comment: @Manochvarma, I have updated my answer, based upon the sample content of the `.cfg` file. _**Note:** Please do not make any changes to the script, run it as it is. There is only one place where modifications can be made and that is below the `Rem`arked line, (which is not required for the purposes of your specific task)._

Comment: Thank you for the code. It works! I understand you have referred to my link that I've provided. Is that possible to make the code following the arrangement of this code `set args=-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Add, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%cd%`? I feel it is more convenient for me. Maybe you don't have to include all the location (ProgramData, Local & Roaming) because that we can set on the `FileLocation` seperately based on our use. I would suggest if you could just create the condition on `if  addon == "CONDITION COMES HERE"` It would be much easier. Hope you can :)

Comment: @Manochvarma, I have not referred to your provided link, which appears to be invalid and doesn't work. I didn't have to help you; you are not my boss, and I haven't agreed to take your instruction. I'm not going dumb down my answer for future readers, if you're willing to remove some of its modularity, and think you can do it better, feel free to do so.

Comment: I have updated the link few hours ago seems the link missing the ‘h’ on the ‘http’. I got 0 knowledge about batch coding. That is why I post my question on this site. I would like to apologise if my way of writing made yo u think I’m instructing you. I am just asking a help for someone to create codes that will work for me. If you are not happy helping me that’s not a problem. I would like to thank you for helping me throughout my hard time searching for the right code. “Knowledge is good to share. Not everyone is pro on every field”. Thank you for taking time to look on this problem.

Comment: @Manochvarma, you wrote, "I am just asking a help for someone to create codes that will work for me.", and "Thank you for the code. It works!". Your statements are conflicting, I have, _despite it being off-topic to do so_, created code which works for you. What makes you think that changing my working code, to that of somebody with "0 knowledge about batch coding", should be necessary? Why would you state, "If you are not happy helping me", when that is what I have done? I'm just not happy to modify working code unnecessarily, _it implies, on your part, ungratefulness, arrogance, or both_.

Comment: The sample code `if addon == "CONDITION COMES HERE"` that i provided on the question was actually given by one of the Prepar3D 3rd party developer. He ask me to change it according to my needs. That's why I kept on asking if you can produce something like that. That's because since he is a developer, he knows well about how the code stated in the SDK will work. I didnt tell your code was wrong. I felt if it was written in that style, maybe it will be more appropriate for the game engine style and easier when someone read it. I got reply from him and he suggest to try use `If not exist %cd%`

Comment: I have added the sample code he suggested on the answer [Edit/] for your reference. The code he provided work to remove the path from the `addon.cfg` file. But I am not sure why it is not adding the path back if the code is not in `addon.cfg` file. Once again, I would like to apologies if the way I explain to you make you feel I am wrong or arrogant. Sorry for it. I have 0 knowledge about batch coding. So, I felt quite difficult to make it work.

Comment: I got this error `'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable  program or batch file'`

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@Echo Off
REM Batch Script for Prepar3D V4
REM Search for the installation path of Prepar3D v4 in registry
If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
    Start "" /D "%__CD__%" "%SystemRoot%\SysNative\cmd.exe" /C "%~f0"&Exit /B)
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4"
Set "Val=SetupPath"
Set "Dir="
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%Key%" /V "%Val%" 2^>Nul'
)Do Set "Dir=%%~B"
If Not Defined Dir GoTo :EOF
If "%Dir:~-1%"=="\" Set "Dir=%Dir:~,-1%"

REM 'Add' or 'Remove' the current Folder 'To' or 'From' the Addon Library (add-on.cfg)
find /c "%cd%" "C:\ProgramData\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4\add-ons.cfg"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
echo found
Set args="-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Remove, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%cd%"
goto done
:notfound
echo notfound
Set args="-Configure: Category=Add-on Package, Operation=Add, FileLocation=ProgramData, Path=%cd%"
goto done
:done
start "" "%Dir%\Prepar3D.exe" "%args%"
```